# When using fetch() in JavaScript how do I render details from the returned object onto the html page

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api

I'm using fecth() with JSON to get some details from a 3rd party API. I then want to display these details in my html so they render on the page.

The API I am using returns details about ski resorts, for example, the resort name, weather conditions and other details.

This is my fetch()

```
async function loadResortName() {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.fnugg.no/search?q=Harpefossen',{
            headers: {
                //'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            dataType: "json",
      });
      const resortName = await response.json();
        console.log(resortName);
        document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = resortName.name
      }
      loadResortName();
```

```
<div id="test1">
   [resort name should display here]             
</div>
```

The console.log returns a complex javascript object that seems to contain nested objects and arrays. I need to be able to render in html on the page:

1. The resort name
2. the wind name, mps and speed
3. condition_description
4. The weather symbol

This is a screen shot from the console of how the object returns. As you can see these details are nested down within the object, but I can't figure out how to access them and render them on the html page, can anyone give me an example of how to do this? with my limited knowledge I thought I'd just be able to do something like resortName.name but this fails.

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: @Krzysztof Krzeszewski I have tried setting a div on the page with the ID test1 and then setting the innerHTML using document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = resortName.name. This returns "undefined".

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I just figured it out document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = resortName.hits.hits[0]._source.name works, but now I have a new question, [0] returns an array. https://api.fnugg.no/search?q=Harpefossen is a search query soon I will make "Harpefossen" dynamic so the user will input a name and the array could be multiple integers [0], [1], [2] I neee to render all of them on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned "https://api.fnugg.no/search?q=Harpefossen" returns more than just the resort name. The response contains all the data that you need.

```
const resp = await fetch('https://api.fnugg.no/search?q=Harpefossen')
const data = await resp.json()
data.hits.hits[0]._source.name // hotel name
data.hits.hits[0]._source.conditions.current_report // weather report
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, I have a slight varriation in that I've doen it like this document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = resortName.hits.hits[0]._source.name which is the same thing. @VijayKumar as you can see this is returning an array of objects shown by the [0.] Do you know if the search term was different and it returned more than 1 object in the array like [0], [1], [2] how would I render all of them?

Comment: For example, https://api.fnugg.no/search?q= would return 19 hits in the array. How would I display all 19 resort names inside my div?

Comment: Once you have got the data in the array. You can use any array method to iterate over each item. If data is an array, then the logic would be like data.forEach(item => /*add to dom*/)

Comment: you might want to use document.createElement and document.appendChild functions.